# EXPRESS : How to prevent Fetch() to repond with cached response

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, fetch

I am facing a very strange issue, I have a middleware where I am making a fetch() call to my API from my Express APP. it looks like :

**Middlware Function**

```
export function handler (req, res, next) {

    if (someURL) {

        return fetch(someURL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            cache: 'no-store'
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                log.info(`called response${response}`);
                log.info(`called response status${response.status}`);
                if (response.status && response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    res.clearCookie('master', { httpOnly: true, secure: true, domain: 'someDomain' });

                    return next();
                }
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                next(error);
            });
    }
}
```

here When I hit that URL that is intercepted with this Middleware, I want the cookie to be cleared and for that i am using the Header with the details above. But When I make this call I get the 200 OK from the disc written in the  chrome network tab and call does not work properly as the cookie expiration headers coming from the APIs are not getting rendered. Can someone Point out what is wrong and how can I stop this caching in-order to get these cookies deleted?

thanks in advance

Comment: Add `cache: 'no-store'` on your server side, not on front end.

Comment: My API is JAVA based any suggestions for that?